# Snakemake Groups & Resources

Tags: snakemake

I'm working on an HPC with several nodes using SLURM. I'm running genetic analysis which require a lot of reading from HDDs. To make use of each nodes `/scratch` storage, I first copy the necessary files with rsync to the node and then run the genetic analysis with the copied files as input. To limit the number of I/O, I set a resource name `rsync_threads` to prevent to much I/O operations.

Since both rules needs to be on the same node, I use grouping. If I set the `rsync_threads` resources to 8, two jobs will get spawned. As soon as the copy step is done, I would like to start another job submission. According to the Snakemake documentation, "Snakemake will request resources for groups by summing across jobs" and therefore blocks another submission. How can I solve this problem?

```
rule copytonode:
        input:
                input_file
        output:
                node_file
        threads:
                4
        group:
                "Step1"
        resources:
                rsync_threads = 4
        shell:
                "copy files to node specific storage"

rule makenode:
    input:  
        node_file
    output:
        output_file     
threads:
        128
        group:
        "Step1"
    shell:
        "Do some analysis with 128 threads"
```